# Laravel combine query with if statement

Tags: ajax, laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

Im working on product filtering using AJAX. Is there any possible way to produce same output as picture shown below using query builder?

[image: Php code]

I have tried union but it’s not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this example gives idea , Try this one

use multiple if statement and get data into DB using joins .

```html
function datatables($request) {
        $data = $this->leftJoin('blog_category', 'blog_category.blog_category_uuid', '=', 'blog_detail.blog_category_uuid')
                ->where('blog_detail.blog_detail_is_deleted', 'NO');

        if ($request->search['value'] != null && $request->search['value'] != '') {
            $keyword = $request->search['value'];
            $data = $data->where(function($query) use ($keyword) {
//                $query->orWhere('activity_type.activity_type_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%');
                $query->orWhere('blog_detail.blog_detail_title', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%');
            });
        }
        if (isset($request->order[0]['dir'])) {
            $data = $data->orderBy('blog_detail.blog_detail_id', $request->order[0]['dir']);
        } else {
            $data = $data->orderBy('blog_detail.blog_detail_created_date');
        }
        $datacount = $data->count();
        $dataArray = $data->select('blog_detail.*', 'blog_category.blog_category_name' , DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(blog_detail.blog_detail_created_date,"%Y-%m-%d") as blog_detail_date'));
        if ($request->length == -1) {
            $dataArray = $dataArray->get();
        } else {
            $dataArray = $dataArray->skip($request->start)->take($request->length)->get();
        }
        return [$datacount, $dataArray];
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! I able to modify my code accordingly after looking at this and it works!

Answer (score 1):

In laravel you can create a model for product say `Product`. Then the query will be like

```
$products = Product::where('product_status', '1');
if ($request->input('minimum_price') && $request->input('maximum_prize')) {
    $products = $products->whereBetween('product_prize', array($request->input('minimum_price'), $request->input('maximum_prize')));
}
if ($request->input('brand')){
    $brand_filter = implode("','", $request->input('brand'));
    $products = $products->whereIn('product_brand', $brand_filter);
}
$products = $products->get();
```

after the execution `$products` contains the products after query.